# How to fetch the date that has been changed in datepicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Am developing an app, which first gets the current date from DatePicker using "Calendar.getInstance()", and then the user changes the date. Now how do I fetch the new date after it has been changed?

Comment: you mean user want to select the date from date picker .

Comment: @PolamReddyRajaReddy Yes you are right and not from datepicker dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declear this .

```
private static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
```

add this coding in onCreate()

```
 // add a click listener to the button
    date_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    // get the current date      
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
    String da = Integer.toString(mMonth)+"/"+Integer.toString(mDay)+"/"+Integer.toString(mYear);
    date_text.setText(da);
```

and this is out side of onCreate()

```
 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        String selectedDate = Integer.toString(mMonth)+"/"+Integer.toString(mDay)+"/"+Integer.toString(mYear);
        date_text.setText(selectedDate);
        System.out.println("selected date is:"+selectedDate);
    }
};

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)  {
    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);        
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            }
        };
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, listener, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

And to retrieve the date as String (Friday, 28/10/2011 15:59:00:0)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss:S");
String date = sdfTime.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Comment: Thanks, but does this work fine with datepicker also? As your code says DatePickerDialog

Comment: Yes, just change the DatePickerDialog to DatePicker.

Comment: However If it doesn't, just use DatePickerDialog, it's the most common.

Comment: Actually, the DatePicker will always show as a dialog if you take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html